# Getting error while exporting project from Eclipse in Android

Tags: android, export, project

I am getting the following error while exporting my project from Eclipse to send it for testing.

```
Obsolete ProGuard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames

Issue: Looks for problems in proguard config files
Id: Proguard

Using -keepclasseswithmembernames in a proguard config file is not correct; it can cause some symbols to be renamed which should not be.
Earlier versions of ADT used to create proguard.cfg files with the wrong format. Instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames use -keepclasseswithmembers, since the old flags also implies "allow shrinking" which means symbols only referred to from XML and not Java (such as possibly CustomViews) can get deleted.

http://http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16384
```

That link is not working for me, and I have no idea how to fix this. I had recently upgraded my ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the following links:

- [android developers](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7606320e664fec9b?pli=1)
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613098/obsolete-proguard-file-use-keepclasseswithmembers-instead-of-keepclasseswithm)
- [bug list](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16384)

Answer (score 0):

I have selected the error in Programs window of eclipse. And error is removed.